# tintcolored area to have border in uiimageview

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uiimage

```
let templateImage = UIImage(named:"marker")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
self.imageView.image = templateImage
self.imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
self.imageView?.tintColor = UIColor.red
self.imageView?.tintAdjustmentMode = .normal
self.imageView.backgroundColor = .clear
```

I'm using Swift 3

[image: output screenshot]

But what I require is the tintcolored area border to be filled with black color as below screenshot:

[image: expected result]

Marker icon is here:

[image: marker icon is here]

Comment: Instead of adding border mentally why you are not making image with black border?

Comment: If I apply `self.imageView.backgroundColor = .black` I will get entire imageview in black. I need border in black only for the tintColored area

Comment: I'm not talking about black background you should make new image *(That you want like black border)* by designer.

Comment: To show what i required i have added required output screenshot edited in mspaint..

Comment: `let templateImage = UIImage(named:"marker")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)` it will convert the image into color which means if designer gives black border also this line tint that too. you can observe that in Marker Icon i added. Marker icon have two colors yellow and black but output is completely in red

Comment: @Ani Using any photo editor make the image with border and then use that image to your image view.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to border the content of the image.  If yes,  then it is not possoble.

You can give border to imageview using below lines:

```
self.imageView.layer.borderwidth = 1 //as per your requirement
self.imageView.layer.borderColor = UIColor. blackColor().CGColor
```

Comment: Yes.. I'm trying to set border for the content of image. If I get the tintcolored area then I guess that, it is possible to achieve this through core graphics classes.. I'm trying to get tintcolored area as of now

Comment: Why don't you add border directly to image? But if you try to set the border to the content then it is not possible.